# Can't place order notes woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I can't edit any order notes when placing an order on my website. I have tried to change the placeholder, but without any success. Someone who knows? Any other field works, except the order notes.

http://postimg.org/image/rbcy021xv/

Comment: What language are you using? have you viewed source of the webpage to see what class has been assigned to the field?

Comment: <p class="form-row notes woocommerce-validated" id="order_comments_field"><label for="order_comments" class="">Order notes</label><textarea name="order_comments" class="input-text " id="order_comments" placeholder="Placeholder goes here!" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea></p>

Comment: If you go to www.evh.se and add a product to the cart, and then tries to add notes in the order note textfield it does not work.

Comment: I can edit the order notes, what browser are you using?

Comment: Hmm, ok! Strange. I am using Chrome.

Comment: I found the problem!

.woocommerce form .form-row input.input-text, .woocommerce form .form-row textarea, .woocommerce-page form .form-row input.input-text, .woocommerce-page form .form-row textarea {
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

When I removed line-height:0; it worked.